# Find Distance Between Points That Have Only Relative Coordinates

Tags: graph-theory, coordinate-systems

Let's say I have an array of points, each of them defined by their distance to surrounding points, rather than by coordinates on a map. For instance, NY's location would be defined by its distance to Pennsylvania and Maryland, etc. And Washington is defined by its distance to Oregon and Idaho, etc.

Assuming each point is defined by a limited number of connections, how would I find the distance between two points that don't share connections, such as NY and WA?

The scenario is a map of node points in 3D space, and rather than defining their coordinates in terms of XYZ on a graph, I'm defining their distances between each other in terms of XYZ. So if Point A is in some location in space with a number of surrounding neighbors, and Point Z is in some other location in space with a number of *other* surrounding neighbors, I want to be able to find the distance between A and Z.

I've already considered a flood method, similar to how simpler pathfinding works, flooding a temporary connection map and finding the shortest path drawn and using that path to figure out a straight line distance. This method seems very costly, however.

Comment: If the point dont have connections, you dont have any form to get their distance?? How supposedly you wil trace a straight line between them, if there is not a map??. Not clear at all.

Comment: Is dynamic programming relevant (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065433/what-is-dynamic-programming) ?

Comment: @hyprfrco No "straight lines" ; consider this issue as a graph theory problem.

Comment: "using that path to figure out a straight line distance"

Comment: @hyprfrco you are right, I didn't notice. The OP must "downgrade" his expectations. He/she will get at best larger distances than straight line distances.

Comment: @JeanMarie What you're talking about sounds like maintaining a cache of solutions. Which might be the best method. Or a very good part of the best method. If I start with two points and figure out the distance between them (for simplicity's sake, let's say they already have a defined connection), then I can save that solution and only ignore it when one of those two points/objects change location in the future. In a very dynamic system, though, this sort of cache/dynamic solution would easily become far less useful.

Comment: @JeanMarie On downgrading my expectations, if I have a map where any two points can have a path drawn between them based on their connections, you would use the average of the changes in direction that it took to get from A to B to define a straight line. If A to B to C to D to E is the shortest path from A to E, then the average change in X, Y and Z gives you your heading from A to E. At least, that's what's worked so far, for me. I'd just like to not have to consider all possible points to figure that out.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the data on which you work. For each node $N_k$, do you consider only three **distances** to three distinct neighbours, making a "vector" in an abstract 3D space of representation. Or, do you have, for each node, 3 **vectors** (making 9 numbers) for "reaching" the three neigbouring nodes ?

Comment: @JeanMarie For each node I do use XYZ, but those XYZ values are distance values to other nodes. So, using US states as examples, NY would have a connection list [PA, NJ, CT, MA, VT], where each of those elements is an XYZ distance. WA would have a connection list [OR, ID]. Pennsylvania, New Jersey, Connecticut, Maryland, Vermont, Oregon and Idaho would also have connection lists that would include NY or WA and, if you follow connection lists, you would eventually find a path from NY to WA. I want to short-cut the heuristic method of following many paths until the best one is found.

Comment: To note, I'm finding that the solution I want involves graph theory, and @JeanMarie might have more or less answered the best (current) way to solve my problem, involving maintaining a cache of solutions.

Comment: Also to add, you might think this is the traveling salesman problem, but I'm not really worried so much about the best path across connections so much as determining what the distance would be between NY and WA, straight line. For example, if I have [pa,pb,pc] and distance values for pa to pb and pb to pc, I can figure out the distance from pa to pc by averaging the change in distances between the known values. But if I have an array that is hundreds of points long and I want to find the distance between two points with no short set of connections to get there, I'm stuck iterating over it all.

Comment: I guess it's worth saying, unless someone wants to correct me, as I'm reading graph theory and considering my problem, there doesn't really seem to be a solid solution to this (yet). So maybe this is a bad question, or a good question for others who might also be wondering, to read "there is no good answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using graph theory you'll get the shortest distance between the two nodes pretty easily assuming the are indirectly connected (this is a classic and you'll find a zillion algorithms and their implementations online).

If you want the euclidian distance then after finding **a** path (you're not forced to have the shortest path, although it might lead to quicker computation) then you'll have to solve a system of equations. Note that for this to work you need to have 2 (or 3 in 3 dimensions) known distance for each and every single node of your path (this might lead you to add nodes outside the path, this is ok as long as those extra nodes also respect the previous rule)

Comment: The way I have it in my head, is each point would have defined neighbors. I'm working out how these neighbors could change where points might move, but using these neighbor lists I could define paths, essentially, between two unconnected points. It kinda seems like that's what you're getting at, something like this.

Comment: Others suggest graph theory as well, and as I'm reading about it (new topic, to me) this is the direction I want to go. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, graphs are a really powerful tool to solve a lot of problem but they are changing the way you think about things like distance.